# SQLAlchemy CAST with NOT LIKE query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

New to SQLAlchemy and having some problems constructing a query that casts the data type for a column from one to another and doing a NOT LIKE query afterwards.

This is what I have currently:

```
not_like_result = MrTS.query.filter(cast(MrTS.rules, String), not_(MrTS.rules.like(search_keyword))).all()
```

From what I understand this is because above code inserts an AND inbetween there because of the comma, when I just want NOT LIKE. Just not sure how to chain it together properly.

Comment: `filter(MrTS.rules.cast(String).notlike(search_keyword))`, but out of interest: what is `MrTS.rules`? Is it some sort of collection? Are you actually trying to check if keyword is (not) in the collection?

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that! Yes, I want to collect the rows which match and the rows that don't match and serialize it into a JSON structure later.

Comment: What's the type of the `rules` column in the database?

Comment: It's of JSONB type. I want to query and see if a key val pair exists within the rules.

Comment: Then you're better off using the proper JSONB operators for the job, instead of simple string matching. Could you please edit the question to include a minimal version of the relevant model and some sample data, and the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one-

```
not_like_result = session.query(MrTS).filter(cast(MrTS.rules, String()).notlike(search_keyword))
```